# How to create jquery Jtable dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, jquery-jtable

I have to dynamically create jquery Jtable based on columns selected by the user. Till now I have done hardcoding the Column names and firing the ajax to get data which will get displayed in jtable.

How to create it dynamically ?

Here is the JS sample code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#StudentTableContainer').jtable({
        title: 'The Student List',
        paging: true, //Enable paging
        pageSize: 10, //Set page size (default: 10)
        sorting: true, //Enable sorting
        defaultSorting: 'Name ASC', //Set default sortin
        fields: {
            StudentId: {
                key: true,
                create: false,
                edit: false,
                list: false
            },
            Name: {
                title: 'Name',
                width: '23%'
            },
            EmailAddress: {
                title: 'Email address',
                list: false
            },
           }
    });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div id="StudentTableContainer"></div>
```

Comment: Hi ! can you please share jsfiddle of your code?

Comment: @SagarR Its a basic simple code of Jtable with three columns and local Values.If you want I can create jsfiddle

Comment: jsfiddle will be of great help.

Comment: @Lara : As vijayP said jsfiddle will be great help... by the way are you working with JAVA?

Comment: No, Server Side Scripting is in .Net. I will share the fiddle shortly

Comment: @SagarR I tried to create One but its not happeing..CSS and JS files are not getting embedded

Comment: @Lara :In jsfiddle you can directly add CDN of respective CSS and JS files.